# glBlitFramebuffer, content is rotated by 90 degree in landscape mode, iOS device (5s and iPad air)

Tags: ios, landscape, blit

i'm not sure it is a device problem or iOS system problem:

on iPhone 5s and iPad Air (they have same cpu/gpu), two same sized framebuffer (1136x640), 
source is a renderbuffer (not a texture), dest is a rendertexture, when glBlitFramebuffer from source to dest, the content will be rotated by 90 degrees in landscape mode.

iOS version is 8.1.3 (iPhone 5s) and 8.2 (iPad Air). because source is a renderbuffer, so drawing a fullscreen quad to dest is not an option.
works fine on iPhone 6 (iOS 10.x) and android, PC (windows).

the only workaround left for now is to glReadPixels, but that would be slow, so what could be the problem? any way to get around this? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i guess it's something about iOS: same device upgraded to the latest iOS version (10.xx), problem solved. tested on another device (iOS 9.xx) and it works fine too.